# twitter bootstrap custom form selectbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have looked through the twitter bootstrap components and can't find any custom form selectbox.
I did find a Split button dropdowns component that looks like what I'm trying to style it like. The problem is I need the form to be able to submit the values of the option selected in the select box. 
Is there a way I can use the Split button dropdowns and have it save the selected value to be submitted  by a form.

Answer (score 13):

Use the jQuery plugin bootstrap-select for this
https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

It transforms your select into a bootstrap dropdown button. It keeps the select to keep the form consistency, so you can submit the selected value.

Comment: is that Support multiple Selektions?

Comment: nope..just regular `<select>`

Comment: Now, as I can see on github this plugin supports multiselect.

Comment: I'm searching for such functionality but for me it's missing the most important one: the search. As here: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="span3">
 <form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="select01">Select list</label>
       <div class="controls">
         <select id="select01" style="width:100%;">
            <option> option1 </option>
            <option> option2 </option>
         </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="review-btn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="this.getvalues()" value="Save changes"/>
    </div>
   </fieldset>
 </form>
</div>
```

in function getvalues(), you can access the selected item thus: $('#select01').val();

Comment: please accept this answer, it works and answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

http://vincentlamanna.com/BootstrapFormHelpers/select.html

I found it recently before I was using Chosen or silvio plugin above.

Or http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ which is the most advanced.